# Push Notifications with NodeJs

Tags: node.js, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I have a group chat implemented in Nodejs and socket.io and mobile application in worklight. Than there is Redis database storing messages. After a new message is send I want to send notification to all devices subscribed. Im have not idea how to put it together to work. I was thinking about adding socket.io to adapter but I founded that I dont know how. Than I was thinking about adding new route to group chat, so adapter can request new messages and process them. Any ideas how to continue or made it the best way?

questions:

Is it possible to invoke worklight adapter from nodejs?

Is it possible to add socket.io to worklight adapter?

Is it possible to periodically invoke worklight adapter?

Is it possible to create no-sql alternative to sql-adapter in worklight?

Comment: Suggested reading: [push notifications node.js](https://www.google.com/search?q=push+notifications+node.js&rlz=1C1TSNP_enUS471US471&oq=push+notifications+node&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.6338j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=0&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: yes,yes,yes,yes yeeeeeeeeeees

Answer (score 1):

*Is it possible to invoke worklight adapter from nodejs?*
Yes. You can invoke a procedure form anywhere. Keep in mind to keep it secure.

*Is it possible to add socket.io to worklight adapter?*
You can keep your socket.io on a separate server and protect it with Worklight

*Is it possible to periodically invoke worklight adapter?*
Yes, server side, create a demon and invoke the Worklight adapter, client side use settimeout.

*Is it possible to create no-sql alternative to sql-adapter in worklight?*
Yes, you can use an HTTP adapter to call the no-sql REST API or call it from a Java adapter.

Comment: Can you please give me brief intro on how to invoke adapter procedure from node.js?